# ion2-calendar show all days in calendar

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am using ion2-calendar in ionic 3, currently, it's allowing to select day starts from today and not previous. I want to select previous days also Please help in this.
I am using the following code,

```
optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
pickMode: 'range',
disableWeeks: [0, 6],
```

};

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You can see previous dates by adding `canBackwardsSelected: true` to the `const options: CalendarModalOptions` then the code will be as follows using **Ionic ModalController**.

```
openCalendar() {
    const options: CalendarModalOptions = {
      title: 'BASIC',
      canBackwardsSelected: true, //By making this true you can access the disabled dates
    };
    let myCalendar =  this.modalCtrl.create(CalendarModal, {
      options: options
    });

    myCalendar.present();

    myCalendar.onDidDismiss((date: CalendarResult, type: string) => {
      console.log(date);
    })
  }
```

Then you just have to call `openCalendar()` from a button click at the HTML end to see enabled past dates.

Answer (score 0):

edit your ts file this will select date between from and to only not after or before

```
test: DayConfig[]=[];
public optionsRange: CalendarComponentOptions = {
  //from: new Date(2019, 0, 1),
  from: new Date(2019, 11, 1),
  to: new Date(2020, 2, 15),
  pickMode: 'range',
  daysConfig: this.test
};
```